# JSF: make f:facet header as commandLink

Tags: jsf, header, facet, commandlink

jsf:

```
<rich:dataTable>
...
    <h:column>
     <f:facet name="header">
      <h:commandLink action="fileSearchSort" styleClass="theader">
       Name
      </h:commandLink>
     </f:facet>
       #{f.name}
    </h:column>
...
</rich:dataTable>
```

if do this:

```
...
    <h:column>
      <h:commandLink action="fileSearchSort" styleClass="theader">
       <f:facet name="header">
        Name
       </f:facet>
      </h:commandLink>
       #{f.name}
    </h:column>
...
```

that label "Name" in header is dissappeared.

Is it possible to do whole `f:facet` header as `commandLink`?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the behaviour you're seeing, the `<f:facet>` is to be nested as direct child of the JSF component which is supposed to own the facet, which is in this case thus the `<h:column>`. Placing it inside a `<h:commandLink>` instead will make it to be the facet of the `<h:commandLink>`, but that component doesn't support a facet with name `header`, so you'll see nothing.

As to the concrete functional requirement, the JSF `<h:commandLink>` component renders a HTML `<a>` element which is by default an [inline](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html) element. If you want to let it occupy the entire space of the parent HTML `<th>` element, then you need to make the `<a>` a [block](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) element instead. Just adding `display: block` to its style class should do.

```css
.theader {
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements of the facet will be rendered into some kind of container, so if you place within the `<h:commandLink>` a `<span>` or `<div>` tag that consumes the entire area then your commandLink should work.

```
<h:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:commandLink action="fileSearchSort" styleClass="theader">
      <span style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      Name
    </h:commandLink>
  </f:facet>
  #{f.name}
</h:column>
```